Docker & Nextjs - ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:<random port> after Docker Desktop update
after updating Docker Desktop (on latest macOS) from 4.29 to 4.30 we've started experiencing ECONNREFUSED errors on random ports when trying to develop our Nextjs 13 app.
We use devcontainers for the development, and the setup is fairly simple - see docker-compose below:
services:
  2on2off:
    container_name: xxx_app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        VARIANT: 18-bullseye
    init: true
    env_file:
      - ../.env
    command: sleep infinity
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ..:/workspace
      - pnpm_store:/workspace/.pnpm-store
      - node_modules:/workspace/node_modules
      - api_node_modules:/workspace/api/node_modules
      - functions_node_modules:/workspace/functions/node_modules
    network_mode: service:db

  db:
    container_name: xxx_db
    image: postgres:14.6-bullseye
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: xxx
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: xxx
      POSTGRES_DB: xxx
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  pnpm_store:
  node_modules:
  api_node_modules:
  functions_node_modules:
  db_data:


pnpm dev starts the development server, but anytime the connection is made we (localhost:3000) get error below. The interesting thing is that the port changes on the start of development server.
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:36821
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1555:16) {
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 36821
}

I've looked into the changelogs of Docker Desktop & it's dependencies but I wasn't able to find anything. The same goes for Nextjs. Downgrade to 4.29 resolves the issue, but that's not the long term solution.
We've tried changing the network settings in docker-compose, but without any result.
What could be the cause?

Your command: sleep infinity is running instead of the image's default CMD.  That artificial sleep command doesn't run a server, and so your container won't be reachable.  Do you mean to delete the command: override; or if the container doesn't do anything, delete the container entirely?  Why do you have four separate named volume mounts to hold libraries, and is it possible the contents of those named volumes isn't what your application is expecting its library stack to be?

sleep infinity is standard approach in devcontainers in order to prevent container termination during startup, and the container itself does something - it acts as environment for the whole development. Apart from that, everything works just fine on 4.29 so that's not the issue.

Ok, so turns out it was Next.js v13.3.1 issue. I've set up new app for testing inside the same devcontainer, and it worked just fine. It used v13.5.6, so I've upgraded the main app to this version and the problem is gone.
